# API Cluster - Using Custom Group Config for Default Endpoint

Tags: javascript, api, endpoint, apicluster

I'm using Api Cluster library. When I try to create multiple `endpoint group` sometime I might want to use default `endpoint` pattern only but config options can be different.

> **Scenario:** if I don't mention 'endpoint' in group then value should be taken from default 'endpoint' pattern

Please have look at this code [click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yinzeqiu2leVTTbJ3Amr?p=preview)

Comment: It just shows "Hello Plunker!" and i'm not seeing anyting.. In the console it is throwing error 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'empDetails' of undefined

Comment: This issue is from library itself and tracked in the Github issue itself. https://github.com/ramsunvtech/apicluster/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of limitation in `API Cluster 1.0.5` JS library.

Because `API Cluster 1.0.5` expect the `addAnother` / `defaults` method parameter requires below three options which is mandatory.

1. name
2. config
3. endpoints

> Defaults / addAnother method creates the endpoint groups, each group is independent

Try like below for your problem.

```
ApiCluster
  .defaults({
    name: 'mydefault',

    config: {
      'employee': 'emp',
      'details': 'defaultDetails',
      'timesheet': 'timesheet'
    },

    endpoints: {
      "empDetails": "_employee_/_details_/:empId/profile"
    }
  })
  .addAnother({
    name: 'v1',
    config: {
      'employee': 'emp',
      'details': 'v1Details',
      'timesheet': 'timesheet'
    },

    endpoints: {
      "empDetails": "_employee_/_details_/:empId/profile"
    }
  });

var empDetailURL = ApiCluster
  .use('v1')
  .get('empDetails')
  .arg({
    'empId': 1000
  })
  .query({
    'confirm': 'yes',
    'testAccount': 'yes'
  })
  .url();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in line #164 (ApiCluster.js)

```
ApiCluster.generated = ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName][name];
```

It is trying to get 'empDetails' from `v1` group.

ApiCluster.generated = ApiCluster.data.apiUrls['v1']['empDetails']

The fix is to change the line to,

```
ApiCluster.generated = ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName] && ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName][name] ? ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName][name] : ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[ApiCluster.data.defaultGroupName][name];
```

So if the property is not available in the requested group then it will read it from defaults.

Here is the url with fix:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ys6btxjYH0xqh1kGuOVf?p=preview

Comment: Nice one. This will be workaround not a fix. look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/Rnj30jIiKb1YWp0T9Akb?p=preview

Comment: It was the fix for the issue reported, for your new issue.. replace with this
    ApiCluster.generated = ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName] && ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName][name] ? ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[groupName][name] : ApiCluster.data.apiUrls[ApiCluster.data.defaultGroupName][name];

Comment: BTW, still issue is not fixed. its returning "emp/details/1000/profile?confirm=yes&testAccount=yes" but expected is "emp/details_emp/1000/profile?confirm=yes&testAccount=yes"

Comment: Got it, The issues needs to be resolved in the ApiCluster library and needs clean up. Not sure on the reason to put it here :)